# Cannot see current debugged line in Visual Studio Code / Python / ptvsd

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ptvs

While remote debugging a simple Python program on a Raspberry, from a PC, it seems to work correctly (hitting F10 or F5 does what it should) except that I cannot see the current line debugged (the current line is not highlighted).

Also, the breakpoints have gray circle instead of red one, so I thing I miss something.

Code being debugged (commented out lines are un-commented on remote machine, of course):

```
# import ptvsd
# ptvsd.enable_attach('my_secret', address=('192.168.1.27', 3000))
# ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
# ptvsd.break_into_debugger()

print("Hello, World!")

for i in range(10):
    print("i = {0}".format(i))
```

and launch.json python attach config:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "192.168.1.27"
    },
```

Any idea?

EDIT: ptvsd version is 3.0.0 on both machines

Thanks a lot

Patrice

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Code, you'll need to install [`ptvsd==2.2.0`](https://pypi.org/project/ptvsd/2.2.0/) rather than 3.0.

The 3.0 series of `ptvsd` is for Visual Studio 2017 only. However, the 4.0 series will be the same for both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. You can install this using `pip install --pre ptvsd` (as it's in preview) and follow [the instructions here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/03/08/python-in-visual-studio-code-feb-2018-release/) to enable it.

Once 4.0 becomes the default (sometime in mid-2018), you will just be able to install the latest `ptvsd` to use with any up-to-date Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.